# change value of next element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an `input` field and `span` like below and want to `replace` the `text` in the `span`.

```
<div>
       <input autofocus="autofocus" type="email" value="" name="buyer_signup_email" id="buyer_signup_email" autocomplete="off">
       //want to change below elements text
       <span class="help-block red-text">will change this text</span>
</div>
```

I tried this but not working

```
$('input[name="buyer_signup_email"]').next().val('dd')
```

Could someone tell me whats wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: Apropos the accepted answer below, the `val()` property is strictly for form elements, such as your `input` element. It is also the value which will ultimately be submitted. The `text()` property is the textual content of a _container_ element, such as your `span` element.

Comment: @Manngo was wondering why..Thank you for the explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `.text()` instead of `.val()`

```
$('input[name="buyer_signup_email"]').next().text('dd')
```